# Spanish verb meaning "to drive through" the city?

Tags: traducción

Is there any verb in Spanish meaning "to drive through"? As in the following example:

> Peter wants **to drive through** the city from East to West to get to his house.

My suggestions are:

- andar
- atravesar
- irradiar
- pasar
- recorrer

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

***Cruzar*** seems to me like the right choice ([see DLE, meaning 4](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BOfplQC)).

***Atravesar*** ([meaning 6](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4KAfNef)) looks good too, but it *could* also mean the starting and ending points are not necessarily *in* the city. (Quite like *drive through* though).

> Peter quiere cruzar/atravesar la ciudad de este a oeste para llegar a su casa

[***Recorrer***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VV8nBVl) also means what you want, but may add some ambiguity since usually it implies you make a number of stops (as in a trip/vacation).

As for the other synonyms you cite:

- [*Andar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2ZGgAPa%7C2ZIziL7): although you *could* say *andar la ciudad*, the verb in its intransitive form is too general (nearly like to go), with a lot of meanings that imply a number of different nuances. Also its use as a transitive verb is not that common.
- *Irradiar* implies a spreading. According to the [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M7ESExh), it is a good choice for a translation of *to irradiate* in the physical sense, that might also extend to a figurative one. I've also seen it used e.g. in architecture for a number of paths departing from a point in different directions or the like.
- *Pasar*. Even if the [DLE suggests](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX) that it could be used in this situation, I'd advise against it, since all examples I can think of involve that both the starting and ending point are outside the city.

Note that none of these verbs adds the sense that you are going *by car*, let alone *driving it yourself*. If you want to put the emphasis on that, I'd use [***manejar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OB053xL) (in Latin America) or [***conducir***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AChIusj) (in Spain):

> Tuve que manejar de un extremo a otro de la ciudad

*(I had to drive through the city from end to end)*: the *through* part is not in the meaning of the verb, but in the complement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree. None of those implies driving. I'd translate that sentence as _Peter quiere cruzar la ciudad de oriente a occidente **manejando** para llegar a su casa_. In English you have to use two words: one for  _drive_ and another for  _through_. In Spanish you also have to use **manejar** for drive and **cruzar, atravesar etc** to express "through” (from end to end)

Comment: I also agree. How about "_Peter quiere **manejar** hasta su casa **atravesando** la ciudad de este a oeste_".